# Symfony2 - how to display/insert an Array in Database from a Form?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony, doctrine

I am stuck with a piece of code that i can't resolve.

I have an Entity, having some arguments. One of them is an Array.

I would like to display it in a Form as several `<select>` tags.

For instance, my array is called param and `$param = array (a,b,c)`, i would like to get a html form like

```
 <select name='param[0]'>
      <option value='0'>0</option>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <select name='param[1]'>
      <option value='0'>0</option>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <select name='param[2]'>
      <option value='0'>0</option>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
```

Then, at the from subsmission, i would like the `$param` array to be inserted in the database as an array.

I have try to use de Collection type, but i couldn't resolve it. 
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much better to use 3 columns instead of arrays.

This way you store value for each of your select elements in a separate column.

Comment: Hi, yes, but i forgot to say that I chose an array representation because the length may vary.

Comment: How much does it vary?

Comment: ideally it may vary from 1 to 99 :)

Comment: In that case array would be better. I see that you have values like 0,1,2, so I think VARBINARY could work for you. Try it out.